# ActiveMQ LIFO ordering?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

Is there any option to change queue order without using out of box "Resequencer"? Maybe it can be done using JMS client to get last message in queue instead of first?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should give more info about what you're trying to achieve...
Anyway if you read the specs of some JMS implementation like MQ you'll see that the FIFO order is not guaranteed at 100%.
That means that if you relay on the order of the messages received, you can get easily in trouble.
It's good practice to add a progressive number to the message header and use it to handle the messages as you please. If you adopt this solution you have 2 options to achieve your goal:
1) modify the receiver business logic to check the the header of the message;
2) (probably the cleaner approach if you're using MQ) use something called **MESSAGE SELECTOR**.

Message Selectors allow content based retrieval of specific messages using SQL92-query functions. MQ spec states:

- The JMS message provides a facility to provide user-defined metadata
  to the JMS message header (outside the actual body of the message).
- JMS programs can take advantage of this facility to select a subset
  of messages based on a selection criteria or, in other words, a JMS
  client can choose only those messages that it is interested in.

Here some more info about the implementation of the two solutions...
The property that you're probably interested in and that you should set before sending the message is JMSCorrelationID that will be set to 1 for the first message, 2 for the second one and so on.

1) Since you're more interested in the message selector, you can skip to the next bullet. Anyway just for reference, if you decide to adopt the solution 1 you can find some good reference in:

http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQQueueBrowser.html

2) Message Selector. 
Your message selector will be an sql string like:  JMSCorrelationID = max(JMSCorrelationID)

If you wanna implement a message selector in java the syntax is:

MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination, messageSelectorString, true); 
ActiveMQObjectMessage objMsg = (ActiveMQObjectMessage) consumer.receiveNoWait();

Comment: Andrea R1, thanks for reply. I have queue with 100 messages inside and I want to process it like a stack. For example messages come to queue in order: 1, 2, 3... 99. But I want to recive it in reverse ordere (not strict, but reverse), like: 98, 99, 97.. 2, 1. I have no idea how to write this selector: "MAX(timestamp)"

Comment: By definition, a queue is meant for FIFO operations.  To reverse the order, push all of the contents into a Stack, and then pop the elements off the stack as you need them.